# Prevent that UWP app is listed in start menu

Tags: uwp, installation, windows-10, windows-10-universal, startmenu

I am developing an AppServiceProvider (UWP app) that is used by an Edge extension. I do not want that the AppServiceProvider app appears in the start menu after installation. If the user clicks on its start menu entry, an empty window is shown after the splashscreen.

Is it possible to create an .appx or .appxbundle that does not appear in the start menu after installation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think this is currently possible. You can however just put some promo/help or user instructions in the app instead of leaving it blank. I think that would make the app's presence in the list warranted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done. Set AppListEntry=none on the VisualElements object.

Note that this will cause store submission to fail for regular apps, so you may need to ask for an exception if you are distributing via the store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-visualelements